# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' When I use libarchive.js

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I'm trying to use [libarchive.js](https://github.com/nika-begiashvili/libarchivejs) to decompress a zip file that protected by a password.

```
import {Archive} from 'libarchive.js/main.js';

Archive.init({
    workerUrl: 'libarchive.js/dist/worker-bundle.js'
});

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', async (e) => {
    const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];

    const archive = await Archive.open(file);
    let obj = await archive.extractFiles();
    
    console.log(obj);
});
```

When I run this code, the console shows below output.
[image]

I have tried many workerUrl like below. But the result is same.

```
workerUrl: 'libarchive.js/dist/worker-bundle.js'
workerUrl: '/libarchive.js/dist/worker-bundle.js'
workerUrl: '../libarchive.js/dist/worker-bundle.js'
workerUrl: '../../libarchive.js/dist/worker-bundle.js'
workerUrl: '/node_modules/libarchive.js/dist/worker-bundle.js'
workerUrl: '../node_modules/libarchive.js/dist/worker-bundle.js'
workerUrl: '../../node_modules/libarchive.js/dist/worker-bundle.js'
```

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `file` is a dom object. You need a src attribute of the file, so instead of passing file, pass the file's src attribute.

Comment: The source code is from the original tutorial page. Is it wrong?

Comment: add console.log(e.currentTarget.files[0])

Comment: https://idiallo.com/javascript/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token#n

Comment: it means "libarchive.js/dist/worker-bundle.js is not exist".

Comment: console.log(e.currentTarget.files[0]) printed 
 {name: "1p.zip", lastModified: 1593413996415, lastModifiedDate: Mon Jun 29 2020 15:59:56 GMT+0900 (Korean Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 166, …}

Archive.open(file) printed "Uncaught SyntaxError:...".

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see this:

```
▶ Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' some-file.js:1
```

It's usually because the request to load `some-file.js` returned an HTML page displaying a `404` error, but it's being interpreted as JavaScript and crashing on the very first character, which in the source of an HTML page is usually `<`.

To solve your problem, you can try the following URL from [this answer](https://github.com/nika-begiashvili/libarchivejs/issues/13#issuecomment-531709476):

```html
/lib/worker-bundle.js
```

Or you can try to view `worker-bundle.js` directly in a browser.  Either you will locate the correct URL, or you will learn that your server is simply not serving that file at all.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code.

```
Archive.init({
    workerUrl: '/libarchive.js/dist/worker-bundle.js',
});
```

And I put libarchive.js in /public folder of my Vue project.
It worked.